# Dynamically formatting a cell based on a range

Tags: excel, formatting

I've read a lot of "conditional formatting" answers, and none of them seem to cove THIS aspect of what I'm trying to do....

I have two questions: (Excel 2010 - windows XP)
1) I have a column that calculates a percentage per row - I also have another cell in that row that has a "base" or "reference" percentage... I want to HIGHLIGHT the cell where the calculated percentage falls OUTSIDE a range based on the "base" percent.

example - base percent is 15.5% (A1) - the calculated row percent is 17% (AA1) -
I want something like this
IF AA1 < sum(A1*.9) AND AA1 > sum(A1*1.1) THEN highlight cell A1

the caveat is that all the "conditional formatting" that does something similar - using the NOT BETWEEN - always seems to convert the cell reference to be ABSOLUTE...meaning when I paste that formula into AA2 or AA3 - it keeps the reference as $A$1...

I need it to change per row....

2) Second question - unrelated - is there some way to LOCK that column ("AA" in my example) so people can't paste data into my formula area?????

thx

Answer (score 0):

1) In the conditional formatting section, use the formula criteria. When your formula returns 1, formatting is applied and 0 it's not applied. So you can do:

`IF (AND(AA1 < sum(A1*.9),AA1 > sum(A1*1.1)), 1, 0)`

As your conditional formatting formula. When you apply it to a range, it acts like dragging the formula from the top left cell of the range to the bottom right cell.

Comment: No Luck Alexandre -
I did that in the formula section of Conditional formatting...
=IF (AND(AS3 < sum(K3*.9),AS3 > sum(K3*1.1)), 1, 0)
-where "AS" is the calc'd val & "k" is the reference val

Then pasted that cell into a range of cells - 
Rows 5-20 - pasted - then clicking on the conditional formatting and 'edit rule' - yields:
=IF (AND(AS3 < sum(K3*.9),AS3 > sum(K3*1.1)), 1, 0)
In ALL rows...
I "want"

=IF (AND(AS5 < sum(K5*.9),AS5 > sum(K5*1.1)), 1, 0)
=IF (AND(AS6 < sum(K6*.9),AS6 > sum(K6*1.1)), 1, 0)
=IF (AND(AS7 < sum(K7*.9),AS6 > sum(K7*1.1)), 1, 0)

Comment: Your formula does not make sense at all. You are saying "if AS3 is both under the lower bound AND over the upper bound, then 1, otherwise 0. This will always result in 0, thus no conditional formatting applied. Finally, you might want to change 1 and 0 to TRUE and FALSE respectively. In my tests in Excel 2007 I could not make it work with 1 and 0 even though I'm pretty sure I made it work another time. In any case, the formula will appear as though it is not changing per cell but it will.

Comment: thx i'll try that - but yes that is my logic - I have a narrow range of +- 10%, if it falls outside either (over or under) I want to highlight the cell - if it is inside the range - than it's fine, no highlight. under the lower limit and over the upper limit leave the range over the lower and under the upper... seems logically sound to me - it there a better way to 'phrase' that logic?? I cant state is as under the upper or over the lower because THOSE cross and extent out infinantly...

Comment: You want "OR" not "AND". No number can be AT THE SAME TIME above AND under another number. For example, 9 is below 10 but not above 10. 11 is above 10 but not below. 10 is neither below nor above 10. In your formula you clearly have AND(condition1, condition2)